# Apache mod_rewrite double encodes query string on redirect

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, querystring, escaping

We've encountered a strange issue (a bug, perhaps?) with Apache mod_rewrite's behavior when passing through query strings.

To reproduce, we've set up a clean Ubuntu (oneiric) install with the default Apache configuration. We have enabled mod_rewrite, and in the default site configuration, we've added the following:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /r/$1 [R]
```

To test, we use curl:

```
curl -I 'http://[ubuntu-machine]/a/b%20c?a%20b'
```

The relevant output is:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Server: Apache/2.2.20 (Ubuntu)
Location: http://[ubuntu-machine]/r/a/b%20c?a%2520b
```

As you can see, the query string is double-escaped, which is wrong. Does anyone have any idea how we could fix this? A couple of things we've tried:

- Adding [NE]. This gives us the correct query string, but the path is unescaped, which leads to new problems.
- Adding [NE,B]. This seems to work, but causes the `/` between the `a` and `b` parts of the path to be escaped.
- Unescaping the query string manually.

  ```
  RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .*
  RewriteMap unescape int:unescape  
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$          $1?${unescape:%{QUERY_STRING}}
  ```

  However, this means we cannot distinguish between, say, an `&` and an escaped `&` in the query-string.

**Update:**

[This bug report](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=50447) describes the same issue. The first comment links to a commit apparently fixing the issue, but as Pieter says below, it doesn't seem like it is actually fixed.

Answer (score 7):

This seems to be a bug in Apache. This bug report is a bit messy, but describes your problem exactly:

https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=34602

It looks like they are aware of the issue. Though the bug claims they have fixed, I have tested this with Apache 2.3.15, and the problem still seems to be there. Also note that Apache 2.3 is a beta version, so it's no use to you even if it did fix it, until Apache 2.4 is out.

Comment: Seems that Apache 2.4.10 is still doing this, though it should have been [fixed in 2.4.1](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=50447).

Comment: I still see the issue in 2.4.7